# Fat tire vs regular mountain bike in mud

Tags: fatbike

Looking to see which one is better suited for me. Mid 50's outta shape and heavy and need the exercise. Will be checking cows and fences. This is mostly flat pasture and hay meadows with lots of wallows from hogs tearing it up.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are 50's outta shape and heavy then mud is going to be hard either way.  If you have sand then maybe go fat tire otherwise go regular for cost.

Comment: Lots of rough ground thou...still reg mnt type?

Comment: Fat bikes are pretty niche and expensive still. I'd say start regular and gain experience. If you want or need a fat bike you'll know

Comment: Reg mnt bike it is and thanks to y'all...

Answer (score 1):

Mud is even difficult for experienced riders. And a fat tires is not always better at mud.  If you need to dig down to get to solid ground a more narrow tire can be better.

Sand is where a fat tire is nice.  But even soft deep sand is going to be a challenge on a fat tire.

I would look for a 29" mountain bike that will take up to 2.4" tires. 
And there are are mud tires.  Mud tires does not just get better traction but they shed the mud better.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a reasonably standard MTB tire simply because a fat tire will have insane rolling resistance that isn't the nicest thing in the world. Any tire that has been rated decent for cornering would be good, because washing out isn't really that nice at all. Or at least a tire that 'gives' a bit, sliding in a corner slightly is much better than instant mud sample.